# Не работает редактирование уже введенного текста в input (скрипт маска)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть готовый скрипт маска для ввода данных в инпут. Его работа не отвечает требованиям юзабилити - "в поле "ИМЯ ФАМИЛИЯ" после того как вбил текст, нельзя его отредактировать тыкнув пальцем в нужное место в тексте, только стереть"

Вот часть кода которая отвечает за ввод данных (маска)

```
window.onload = function(){
$(function($){
    $("#acctNumber").mask("999999");
    $("#sumCheck").mask("99999");
    $("#cardNumber").mask("9999 9999 9999 9999?999");
    $("#cardCode").mask("999");
});
```

Полный код:

```js
'use strict';

Date.prototype.get2Year = function() {
  return this.getFullYear().toString().substr(2);
};


$(function($) {
  $("#acctNumber").mask("999999");
  $("#sumCheck").mask("99999");
  $("#cardNumber").mask("9999 9999 9999 9999?999");
  $("#cardCode").mask("999");
});

var selectOption = document.createElement('option'),
  optionYear = document.getElementById('optionYear'),
  currentYear = new Date().get2Year();

for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  var newOption = selectOption.cloneNode(),
    year = currentYear++;
  newOption.innerHTML = year;
  newOption.value = year;
  optionYear.appendChild(newOption);
}

var validator = {
  required: function($el) {
    return $el.val() != '';
  },
  num: function($el) {
    var re = /[0-9]/;
    return re.test($el.val());
  },
  latin: function($el) {
    var re = /[a-zA-Z]/;
    return re.test($el.val());
  },
  twoWords: function($el) {
    var re = /(\w+) (\w+)/;
    return re.test($el.val());
  },
  markAsError: function($el, error_msg) {
    $el.addClass('error').next().html(error_msg);
  },
  messages: function(rules) {
    switch (rules) {
      case 'required':
        return 'Поле не заполнено';
        break;
      case 'num':
        return 'Num field';
        break;
      case 'latin':
        return 'Поле должно содержать только латинские символы';
        break;
      case 'twoWords':
        return 'Поле должно содержать имя и фамилию';
        break;
    }
  },
  unMarkAsError: function($el) {

    $el.removeClass('error').next().html('');
  }
};

$('#cardHolder').on('keydown keyup', function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});

$('#validateForm').on('submit', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $inputs = $this.find('input.need-validate'),
    is_valid = true;

  $inputs.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      rules = $this.data('validate').split(' ');

    for (var i = 0, ci = rules.length; i < ci; i++) {

      if (!validator[rules[i]]($this)) {
        validator.markAsError($this, validator.messages(rules[i]));
        is_valid &= false;
        return;
      } else {
        validator.unMarkAsError($this);
      }
    }
  });

  return is_valid === true;
});

$('#resetValidateForm').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $('#validateForm');
  validator.unMarkAsError($form.find('input[type!="submit"]'));
  document.getElementById('validateForm').reset();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/master/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<form id="validateForm" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="owner">
    <label class="param">Владелец</label>
    <input id="cardHolder" data-validate="required latin twoWords" class="need-validate" value="" placeholder="Ivan Ivanov" type="text">
    <div id="errName" class="error-message"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="number-card">
    <label class="param">Номер банковской карты</label>
    <input id="cardNumber" data-validate="required num" class="need-validate" value="" type="text">
    <div id="errCard" class="error-message"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="select-form">
    <div class="flex-itm">
      <div class="margin-right">
        <label class="param">Срок действия</label>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <select class="select-input">
          <option value="01">01</option>
          <option value="02">02</option>
          <option value="03">03</option>
          <option value="04">04</option>
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="06">06</option>
          <option value="07">07</option>
          <option value="08">08</option>
          <option value="09">09</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
        </select>
        /
        <select id="optionYear" class="select-input"></select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-itm">
      <div class="margin-left">
        <label class="param">CVV2/CVC2</label>
        <span id="about" class="about-button"></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input id="cardCode" data-validate="required num" class="need-validate width-input" value="" type="text">
        <div id="errCode" class="error-message"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-button">
    <div class="flex-itm">
      <div class="margin-right">
        <a id="resetValidateForm" class="button-cancel ">Отмена</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-itm">
      <div class="margin-left">
        <input id="validateFormSubmitButton" type="submit" class="button" value="Оплатить">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/asfpy3eb/)

Тут сам скрипт с маской [скрипт](http://cyberapp.ru/2011/07/06/jquery-maskedinput/)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35214/discussion-on-question-by-marina-voronova-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема в этом обработчике

```
$('#cardHolder').on('keydown keyup', function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Так как меняется весь текст, курсор переходит в его конец, а так как это и на нажатие кнопки и на отжатие - то практически на любое действие курсор передвигается в конец введенной строки.

Здесь лучше не мудрить с кодом, а использовать вместо него css свойство:
[text-transform: uppercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform)

Comment: Спасибо! все работает

Comment: этот обработчик был необходим, т.к. на сервер должны передаваться символы в верхнем регистре. переделала так `var $card_holder = $('#cardHolder'); $card_holder.val($card_holder.val().toUpperCase());`

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, переводить достаточно один раз при использовании, хватило бы `var cardholdervaule = $card_holder.val().toUpperCase();` и потом просто использовать его. Ваш код из комментария - не понял, если он находится **внутри** данного обработчика - нет никакой разницы, если нет - тогда непонятно где он вызывается